# Deserialize JSON string embedded within JSON directly

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I'm using .netcore 3.1 and I'm using `System.Text.Json` for serialization and deserialization. I didn't know how to phrase my question precisely. I looked around but couldn't find a direct answer for my question.

Apologies if it's a duplicate.

This is a sample JSON response.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "subscriptionId": "sub1",
        "usageStartTime": "2015-03-03T00:00:00+00:00",
        "usageEndTime": "2015-03-04T00:00:00+00:00",
        "instanceData": "{\"Microsoft.Resources\":{\"resourceUri\":\"resourceUri1\",\"location\":\"Alaska\",\"tags\":null,\"additionalInfo\":null}}",
        "quantity": 2.4000000000,
        "meterId": "meterID1"
    }
}
```

I'm interested in **directly parsing** `instanceData`.
If you observe closely, `instanceData` is an embedded JSON string.

```
{
    "Microsoft.Resources": {
        "resourceUri": "resourceUri1",
        "location": "Alaska",
        "tags": null,
        "additionalInfo": null
    }
}
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to parse this `instanceData` while the whole Json is being parsed? Can we add some **Attributes** to `instanceData` field for direct parsing? Right now, I'm accessing the string from the parsed model class and parsing `instanceData` separately.

This is what I'm doing right now (something like this):

`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MicrosoftResources>(parsedResponse.instanceData)`.

I have already built model classes for `instanceData` and other entities. Currently, `instanceData` is of type `string` in my root model class.

Comment: There are a couple of similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568647/system-text-json-deserialize-nested-object-from-api-call-data-is-wrapped-in-pa) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401444/system-text-json-deserialize-nested-object-as-string). You approach seems to be acceptable as well, just try to change type of `instanceData ` from `string` to `MicrosoftResources`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski changing type to `MicrosoftResource` is the first thing I tried. The deserialization failed that's why I posted this question. The failure is expected since from the deserializer's perspective, `instanceData` is a String not a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested in directly parsing instanceData. If you observe closely, instanceData is an embedded JSON string
>
> Is it possible to parse this instanceData while the whole Json is being parsed?

You can achieve above requirement by creating and using a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to), like below.

```
public class ResConverter : JsonConverter<InstanceData>
{
    public override InstanceData Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //you can implement it based on your actual requirement
        //...

        string jsonData = reader.GetString();

        var instanceData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InstanceData>(jsonData);

        return instanceData;
    }
```

Model Classes

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset UsageStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset UsageEndTime { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ResConverter))]
    public InstanceData InstanceData { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public string MeterId { get; set; }
}
    
public class InstanceData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Microsoft.Resources")]
    public MicrosoftResources MicrosoftResources { get; set; }
}

public class MicrosoftResources
{
    public string ResourceUri { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public object Tags { get; set; }
    public object AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Test code and result

```
var jsondata = "{\"Properties\":{\"SubscriptionId\":\"sub1\",\"UsageStartTime\":\"2015-03-03T00:00:00+00:00\",\"UsageEndTime\":\"2015-03-04T00:00:00+00:00\",\"InstanceData\":\"{\\u0022Microsoft.Resources\\u0022:{\\u0022ResourceUri\\u0022:\\u0022resourceUri1\\u0022,\\u0022Location\\u0022:\\u0022Alaska\\u0022,\\u0022Tags\\u0022:null,\\u0022AdditionalInfo\\u0022:null}}\",\"Quantity\":2.4,\"MeterId\":\"meterID1\"}}";

MyModel myModel = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(jsondata);
```

[image]

Comment: The custom converter solution is basically doing what I'm doing right now with "lots of extra steps". Here's what I'm doing : `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InstanceData>(parsedModel.InstanceData)`. While your solution works, it's an engineering over-kill and I wouldn't recommend it. Therefore, I will upvote your answer but I cannot mark it accepted since there's no straightforward way of doing this. Even [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796081/parse-nested-json-string-in-c-sharp/26796968?noredirect=1#comment108583417_26796968), the .NET guru mentions there's no solution

Answer (score -1):

If you can change the `instanceData` to Json instead of string like this.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "subscriptionId": "sub1",
        "usageStartTime": "2015-03-03T00:00:00+00:00",
        "usageEndTime": "2015-03-04T00:00:00+00:00",
        "instanceData": {"Microsoft.Resources":{"resourceUri":"resourceUri1","location":"Alaska","tags":null,"additionalInfo":null}},
        "quantity": 2.4000000000,
        "meterId": "meterID1"
    }
}
```

You can easily deserialize your Json using the example below.

Model Classes:

```
public partial class Properties
{
    [JsonPropertyName("properties")]
    public PropertiesClass PropertiesProperties { get; set; }
}

public partial class PropertiesClass
{
    [JsonPropertyName("subscriptionId")]
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("usageStartTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset UsageStartTime { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("usageEndTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset UsageEndTime { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("instanceData")]
    public InstanceData InstanceData { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("quantity")]
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("meterId")]
    public string MeterId { get; set; }
}

public partial class InstanceData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Microsoft.Resources")]
    public MicrosoftResources MicrosoftResources { get; set; }
}

public partial class MicrosoftResources
{
    [JsonPropertyName("resourceUri")]
    public string ResourceUri { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
    public object Tags { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("additionalInfo")]
    public object AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // escaped version, just for demo
        var json =
            "{\r\n    \"properties\": {\r\n        \"subscriptionId\": \"sub1\",\r\n        \"usageStartTime\": \"2015-03-03T00:00:00+00:00\",\r\n        \"usageEndTime\": \"2015-03-04T00:00:00+00:00\",\r\n        \"instanceData\": {\"Microsoft.Resources\":{\"resourceUri\":\"resourceUri1\",\"location\":\"Alaska\",\"tags\":null,\"additionalInfo\":null}},\r\n        \"quantity\": 2.4000000000,\r\n        \"meterId\": \"meterID1\"\r\n    }\r\n}";
        var props = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Properties>(json);

    }
}
```

Props will have all of the data. I hope this helps.

Comment: If I had the transcendental power to change the JSON response of an external Microsoft API, I wouldn't have posted this question in the first place. Would I?